# Adjoint semi-simple algebraic groups over non-algebraically closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $G$ be an adjoint semi-simple algebraic group over $k$.

On p34 of the paper "Sansuc - Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes
algébriques lineaires sur um corps de nombres", it is claimed that there exists a collection of finite field extensions $k \subset k_i$ such that
$$G \cong \prod_i \mathrm{R}_{k_i/k}(G_i) \quad (*)$$
where the $G_i$ are absolutely simple adjoint groups over $k_i$ and $\mathrm{R}_{k_i/k}$ denotes the Weil restriction.

I was quite surprised when I saw this, as it certainly seems to be something special about adjoint groups. However, Sansuc unfortunately gives no explanation nor reference why this holds.

> Why does the stated isomorphism (*) exist?

I would be happy with either a proof or a reference.

Comment: This result goes back to Borel and Tits: see 6.21(ii) in their IHES 27 paper (same proof for the adjoint case).  Their proof is as in zeno's answer, since they work throughout with groups over fields (i.e., the idea to introduce the finite etale $k$-algebra $k' = \prod k_i$ and the $k'$-group $G' = \coprod G_i$ so as to write the right side as ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}(G')$ is something that comes very naturally when one is accustomed to considering groups over rings but might look weird otherwise; treating $k'$ as a single package is very handy when contemplating scalar extension on $k$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Proposition 6.4.4 and Remark 6.4.5 in Brian Conrad's article "Reductive groups schemes" in "Autour des schemas en groupes, Vol. I" (alternatively, http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3smf.pdf) for a proof (in a more general setting).

As you mention, this is special for adjoint groups (but would also work for simply connected groups).

Comment: I guess the characteristic 0 hypothesis in the question is irrelevant here?

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Good point. Also, the cited result shows that in positive characteristic the appearing finite extensions $k_i$ may be chosen to be separable.

Comment: Not only can the $k_i/k$ be chosen to be separable: they *must* be separable.  That is, if $k'/k$ is a finite extension of fields that is not separable and $G'$ is a nontrivial connected reductive $k'$-group then ${\rm{R}}_{k'/k}(G')$ is a smooth connected affine $k$-group that is *never* reductive (in brief, nonzero nilpotents in $k' \otimes_k \overline{k}$ give rise to a nontrivial geometric unipotent radical, as is seen concretely for $G' = {\rm{SL}}_n$).

Answer (score 2):

The proof is quite easy. Let $G$ be a simply connected (or adjoint) semisimple
group over a field $k$. Over the separable closure $k^{s}$ of $k$, $G$ is a
product $G=G_{1}\times\cdots\times G_{n}$ of almost-simple groups $G_{i}$. The
Galois group $\Gamma$ of $k^{s}/k$ acts on the set $\{G_{1},\ldots,G_{n}\}$
and the product of the groups in an orbit is stable under $\Gamma$, and hence
defined over $k$. In this way, $G$ is a product of quasi-simple groups over
$k$. Thus, we may suppose that $G$ itself is quasi-simple. Now $\Gamma$ acts
transitively on the set  $\{G_{1},\ldots,G_{n}\}$. Let $\Delta$ be the
stabilizer of $G_{1}$, and let $K$ be the subfield of $k^{s}$ fixed by
$\Delta$. Then $Res_{K/k}(G_{1})$ and $G$ are isomorphic over $k^s$, by an
isomorphism invariant under the action of of $\Gamma$, and so they are
isomorphic over $k$.

Comment: Thanks. Though can you please emphasise at which point in the argument you use that $G$ simply connected or adjoint?

Comment: The second sentence of the proof: in general $G$ will only be isogenous to such a product.

Comment: Curiously, the proof becomes a bit easier if one doesn't pass to the quasi-simple case, as one can formulate the result with a strong uniqueness aspect (pinning down $(k'/k, G')$ uniquely *up to unique isomorphism*, with $k'$ a nonzero finite etale $k$-algebra and $G'$ a smooth affine $k'$-group whose fibers are connected semisimple, absolutely simple, and simply connected -- or adjoint); that handles the Galois descent by pure thought.  See Proposition A.5.14 in the book "Pseudo-reductive groups" for such a proof, the version over fields for the reference given by Cesnavicius over rings.